# ReferenceError: url is not defined

Tags: php, ce-1.8.1.0, javascript, css, html

i get this error in firebug on my magento home page: `ReferenceError: url is not defined`
on this line :

```
return window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like someone has inserted some javascript in you head element. At see ~ line 110 of your dom.

```
<script>
    function popupwindow(w, h) {
      var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
      var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
      return window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
    }
    popupwindow();
<script>
```

This is trying to open a new browser window. However the "url" of the browser window is undefined. ie no (var url = "http://some.domain.com");

I'd check your System -> General -> Design -> HTML Head -> Misc Scripts and remove if you haven't added your self. This also could be inserted by a third party extension you have recently installed.

If this popup is intentional and the code has been added by you. I'd suggest you define the url before you call this function.

See below

```
   <script>

    var url ="http://some.domain.com";

    function popupwindow(w, h) {
      var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
      var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
      return window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
    }
    popupwindow();
<script>
```